Chunked Transfer Encoding, state:READING_LENGTH in Intellij
While accessing Gitlab from IntelliJ to fetch or pull, my account is already logged in but it asks again for password, while entering the password it shows me this error:
chunked transfer encoding, state:READING_LENGTH.

Could'nt find any solution for this, anyone knows what this is?
It is working from terminal using id,password and typing git commands.

I tried fetching and pulling remotes from Intellij UI, but it came with a new error and could not find a solution for this.

There is a workaround described here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-148688/GitLab-chunked-transfer-encoding-state-READINGLENGTH

We currently have no solution for this. Please see:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-160394
Please Please enable debug logs (Help - Diagnostic Tools - Debug Log Settings...) for the following categories
org.jetbrains.plugins.gitlab:trace
Then please reproduce the issue and share the entire logs folder zipped as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files in the comment of the issue

Just followed the above step  putting org.jetbrains.plugins.gitlab:trace in Help -> Diagnostic Tools -> Debug Log Settings... and tried running, It is working fine now
Thanks aLot
